# Does market cap include ALL shareholders, including a company's founders and largest institutional investors?

Tags: corporation, market-capitalization

If a given company has a $100B market cap, does that include *all* of its shares, or is that only the ones which are publicly traded? Are the founders' shares included in the count, as well as those held by huge entities like BlackRock and Vanguard etc?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, by definition the market cap is the total market value of all the shares.

Comment: This would be a better answer with a link or other evidence.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Market_capitalization

Comment: Sometimes simple answers are the best.  However, market cap might be subjective in private/untraded classes of shares that have different ownership/voting rights to those that are publicly traded.  e.g. Google Class B shares.